# How to scrape the data from company's intranet?

Tags: python, web-scraping

**Background:**
For any of my company's internal websites, I need to use VPN to login if I'm not using the company's network. To log in, I need my user name and password.
The web page that I want to scrape not only requires the my user name and password, but also requires additional permission to log in.

**Problem statement:**
I've already got the permission to view this web page(I can view that web page using my username and password), but the code I tried in the following still returns error:

```py
POST_LOGIN_URL = 'https://login.com'
REQUEST_URL = 'https://webpageIneedtoscrape.com'
payload = {
    'username': 'user',
    'pass': 'password'
}
with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
    print(r.text)
```

This gave me the

```py
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https://webpageIneedtoscrape.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:  (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Then I tried to only scrape the homepage of the intranet website using the following code:

```py
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

r = requests.get("https://login.com\\username",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('username','password'))
```

It returned this error:

```py
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.com%5cusername', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

I'm confused that whether I can scrape the intranet or not now. I search online and see some answers talking about certificate, but I don't know what it is.
I'm new to web scraping and I want to know if this problem is able to be solved by myself or it requires additional file, like the certificate?

I also appreciate any advice that help me diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your request:

```
r = session.get(REQUEST_URL, verify = False)
```

As the error indicates, you are failing on certificate verification. Alternatively you can try:

```
r = session.get('https://google.com', verify='/path/to/certfile')
```

ref - https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification